# How to enable void bool from another class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to use saveLevel (this.saveLevel(true);) from another class, and didnt find how to do it.

```
public void saveLevel(bool binary = true)
{
List<LevelEditor.ObjectsSource> list = new List<LevelEditor.ObjectsSource>();
if (this.validationResult.hasTDSotMObjects)
{
    list.Add(LevelEditor.ObjectsSource.DLC1);
}
this.levelData.objectSources = list.ToArray();
LevelEditor.levelDirPath = LevelEditor.createLevelDirIfNotExists(LevelEditor.levelDirPath);
string text = System.IO.Path.Combine(LevelEditor.levelDirPath, "Content");
Directory.CreateDirectory(text);
string path = "Level" + ((!binary) ? ".json" : ".sap");
string path2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(text, path);
LevelEditor.saveLevelData(this.levelData, path2, binary);
```

This is from the class LevelEditor
I'm trying to use it on the class Game, but wont work

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with “won’t work?” You should help us to help you, and provide a bit more details on what you expect from your code, what errors you get or how exactly it does not give you the results you expect, and what results you get.... also, reducing the code to the minimum code that gives your issue helps people check it.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, true, I just want to use this.saveLevel(true); ( from the class LevelEditor) to another class ( game) , but it said, Game does not contain a definition for saveLevel , and I dont know how I can use it from another class except his main class (LevelEditor)

Comment: the `this` keyword refers to "this instance of the class" you wrote `this` in. You cant call `this.SomeMethodFromAnotherClass();` that doesnt even make sense in "normal language" terms. If you want to call a non-static method from another class, you first need a reference (~variable) to an instance of it, then you can call `otherClassInstanceName.SomeMethodFromThatOtherClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to create an instance of `LevelEditor` first, or make it a static method. Look into the [static keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static).

```
var levelEditor = new LevelEditor();

// Methods should be CamelCased
levelEditor.SaveLevel(true);
```

or

```
public class LevelEditor
{
    // Marked this method 'static'
    public static void SaveLevel(bool binary = true)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}

// call like this:
LevelEditor.SaveLevel(true);
```

Comment: But I cant use "this." in a static method, so how can I do it please ?

Comment: If you want to use 'this' inside SaveLevel, use the first option. You need an instance of LevelEditor.

Comment: Read about the difference between static and instance methods and variables in order to understand what's happening. It's basic knowledge, and you need to know if you want to write a C# program.